# Scipy Optimise with Mystic - constraint keeps getting violated

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize, mystic

I'm trying to optimize a 52x5 matrix to maximize a return value `y`. I first flatten the matrix into an array of 260 elements, then apply Scipy optimize and mystic. However, the `max_limit` constraint keeps getting violated?

Please see the main part of the code below:

```
max_limit = 2000

def constraint_func():
    var_number = ['x'+str(i) for i in range(260)]
    constraint = ' + '.join(var_number) + f' <= {max_limit}'

    return constraint

eqns = ms.simplify(constraint_func(), all=True)
constraint = ms.generate_constraint(ms.generate_solvers(eqns), join=my.constraints.and_)

def objective_func(x):
    constraint_vars = constraint(x)
    y =  -model.func(constraint_vars)
    return y

initial_matrix = [random.randint(0,3) for i in range(260)]

output = so.minimize(objective_func, initial_matrix, method='SLSQP',bounds=[(0,max_limit)]*260 ,tol=0.01, options={ 'disp': True, 'maxiter':100})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the `mystic` author.  Your code is incomplete above, so I'm going to make some assumptions to produce a full working example.

I'm guessing that the constraints are not getting violated, I'm guessing that you are looking at the result from the `scipy.optimize` result object, which is preserving the **unconstrained** value of x.

Let's use a simple model function that's just the sum of the parameter vector.  I also note that you only have a single constraint (i.e. sum(x) <= 2000), so you don't need `all=True` or `join=and_` in the constraints definition. It doesn't hurt to keep them, however.

```
Python 3.8.16 (default, Dec  7 2022, 05:25:02) 
[Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import random
>>> import mystic as my
>>> import mystic.symbolic as ms
>>> import scipy.optimize as so
>>> 
>>> def model_func(x):
...     return sum(x)
... 
>>> max_limit = 2000
>>> 
>>> def constraint_func():
...     var_number = ['x'+str(i) for i in range(260)]
...     constraint = ' + '.join(var_number) + f' <= {max_limit}'
...     return constraint
... 
>>> eqns = ms.simplify(constraint_func(), all=True)
>>> constraint = ms.generate_constraint(ms.generate_solvers(eqns), join=my.constraints.and_)
>>>
```

The problem is that `scipy` considers your `objective_func` in the result object, so that means it tracks `y` for a given `x`, defined by `y = objective_func(x)`, and as is, your constrained `x` that you are interested in tracking is only known **inside** `objective_func` as `constraint_vars`.  So, if you are ok with being a little inefficient (i.e. being a bit lazy and doing a minimal rewrite of your code), then we can use one of mystic's monitors to get the value of `constraint_vars`.  I'm going to use a callback to do that, so we capture the desired values after each iteration.

```
>>> mon = my.monitors.VerboseMonitor(1)
>>> 
>>> def objective_func(x):
...     constraint_vars = constraint(x)
...     y = -model_func(constraint_vars)
...     return y
... 
>>> def callback(x):
...     constraint_vars = constraint(x)
...     y = -model_func(constraint_vars)
...     mon(constraint_vars, y)
...     return
... 
>>> initial_matrix = [random.randint(0,3) for i in range(260)]
```

We can see the results being printed to the verbose monitor, and we can see the difference extracting the results from the monitor, as opposed to from the result object.

```
>>> output = so.minimize(objective_func, initial_matrix, method='SLSQP', bounds=[(0,max_limit)]*260 ,tol=0.01, options={'disp':True, 'maxiter':100}, callback=callback)
Generation 0 has ChiSquare: -681.0
Generation 1 has ChiSquare: -1980.9999999999995
Generation 2 has ChiSquare: -1999.9999999999961
Generation 3 has ChiSquare: -1999.9999999999998
Optimization terminated successfully    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: -1999.9999999999998
            Iterations: 4
            Function evaluations: 1050
            Gradient evaluations: 4
>>> 
>>> print("cost: %s" % output.fun)
cost: -1999.9999999999998
>>> print("unconstrained: %s" % model_func(output.x))
unconstrained: 2102.450852711366
>>> print("constrained: %s" % model_func(mon.x[-1]))
constrained: 1999.9999999999998
>>> print("callback: %s" % mon.y[-1])
callback: -1999.9999999999998
```

The constrained solution is found at `mon.x[-1]`.

Comment: Hi Mike. I've tried your solution, ```Mon.x[-1]``` doesn't break the max_limit constraint. However, the first element of ```Mon.x[-1]``` is a huge negative number which is breaking the ```bounds``` constraint. Not sure why this is the case?

Comment: Ah... if you have a bounds constraint (i.e. x>0), you will also need to add in the bounds constraint to the constraints operator.   In mystic's solvers, it's a bit more integrated... but using mystic with an external solver, what you'll have to do is add the bounds constraints explicitly into the constraints operator as several inequalities.

Comment: See: https://github.com/uqfoundation/mystic/blob/master/examples2/knapsack.py

Comment: ...related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75535468/2379433

Comment: Hi Mike, many thanks for your response. However, I'm still getting issues with mystic - I have made a new post for it and have included full code :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75566236/scipy-mystic-constraints-violated-after-being-specified

Comment: addressed it in the new post