# Scipy / Mystic - Constraints violated after being specified

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize, mystic

I'm trying to optimize a 10x5 matrix to maximize a return value y, using mystic. There are 2 types of constraints that I need to include:

1. Each element must be in between a min and max range
2. Some elements must equal specific values (provided in a dictionary)

Not sure why the optimized result includes negative values as I have already made a constraint for that (constraint no.1) and the return y value seems to be incredibly small?

```
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import mystic.symbolic as ms
import mystic as my
import scipy.optimize as so

# Specifiying constraints
element_low_lim = 0
element_hi_lim = 1000
total_matrix_min_sum = 0
total_matrix_max_sum = 220000

# Create an input matrix where the values must equal a specific amount
matrix_in = np.zeros((52,5))
matrix_in[0,0] = 100


def constraints_func(element_low_lim, element_hi_lim, total_matrix_min_sum, total_matrix_max_sum,element_vals_dict):
    var_num = ['x'+str(i) for i in range(260)]

    #creating element bounds constraints
    constraint_bound = ''
    for var in var_num:
        if var not in element_vals_dict:
            constraint_bound += var + f' >= {element_low_lim}' + '\n' + var + f' <= {element_hi_lim}' + '\n'

    #creating sum of all the elements constraint
    constraint_matrix_sum = ' + '.join(var_num) + f' <= {total_matrix_max_sum}' + '\n' + ' + '.join(var_num) + f' >= {total_matrix_min_sum}'


    #creating element constraints
    constraint_elements = '\n'.join([var+' == '+str(element_vals_dict[var]) for var in element_vals_dict])

    # bundle all constraints
    constraint_equations = constraint_bound.lstrip() + constraint_matrix_sum.lstrip() + constraint_column_sum.lstrip() + constraint_elements.lstrip()

    return constraint_equations

equations = constraints_func(element_low_lim, element_hi_lim, total_matrix_min_sum, total_matrix_max_sum, column_sum_min_lst, column_sum_max_lst, element_vals_dict)
equations = ms.simplify(equations, all=True)
constrain = ms.generate_constraint(ms.generate_solvers(equations), join=my.constraints.and_)

# Define Objective function
def obj_func(matrix):
    return np.sum(output_matrix)

mon = my.monitors.VerboseMonitor(1)

objs = []
def callback(x):
    kx = constrain(x)
    y = -obj_func(x)
    mon(kx, y)
    objs.append(y)
   
# create a starting matrix
start_matrix = [random.randint(0,3) for i in range(200)]

# run optimizer
solution = so.minimize(obj_func, start_matrix, method='SLSQP', tol=0.01, options={'disp': True, 'maxiter':100}, callback=callback)
```

Comment: Hi Mike, have tried running the update made to the code. The code seems to get stuck here?

```equations = constraints_func(element_low_lim, element_hi_lim, total_matrix_min_sum, total_matrix_max_sum, column_sum_min_lst, column_sum_max_lst, element_vals_dict)```

```equations = ms.simplify(equations, all=True)```

```constrain = ms.generate_constraint(ms.generate_solvers(equations), join=my.constraints.and_)```

Comment: see my answer.  What I generally do, is print the equations and then try to come up with strategy to simplify them.  There are some things that `mystic` needs help with... and suggestions on which variables to tweak to ensure the constraints are respected are useful.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns Hi Mike,

Would greatly appreciate if you can provide advice on how to solve this separate problem - I'm basically trying to optimize batch intervals. Not sure how to go about solving it. Please see the link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76070398/batch-interval-optimisation

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are running into is that `mystic` could use some help in simplifying the equations so that they are most likely to succeed when imposing the constraints.

You have `x0`, `x1`, and `x2` as fixed. However, in your sum constraints, simplify will (by default) isolate the first variable in the list on the LHS -- where the isolated variable is the one that the constraints adjust. So, having `x0` fixed, and then expecting it to be adjusted to resolve the sum constraints is a **bad** idea.  `mystic` will attempt to resolve the constraints, but fail and give up.

What you want to do is isolate the "non-fixed" variables in the sum constraints.  I've rewritten your code to do that.

```
>>> import random
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import mystic.symbolic as ms
>>> import mystic as my
>>> import scipy.optimize as so
>>> 
>>> # Specifiying constraints
>>> element_low_lim = 0
>>> element_hi_lim = 20000
>>> total_matrix_min_sum = 0
>>> total_matrix_max_sum = 20000
>>> column_sum_min_lst = [0,0,0,0,0]
>>> column_sum_max_lst = [10000,2000,8000,0,0]
>>> 
>>> # Create an input matrix where the values must equal a specific amount
>>> matrix_in = np.zeros((52,5))
>>> matrix_in[0,0] = 100
>>> matrix_in[0,1] = 200
>>> matrix_in[0,2] = 300
>>>
>>> # Create a dictionary of elements constraints (i.e create a dict of where value is non-zero)
>>> flat_mat = matrix_in.flatten()
>>> nonzero_idx = np.where(flat_mat>0)
>>> nonzero_vals = flat_mat[nonzero_idx]
>>> element_vals_dict = dict(zip(['x'+str(i) for i in nonzero_idx[0]], nonzero_vals))
```

Broken up the constraints functions to make them easier to deal with in simplify.

```
>>> def constraints_func0(element_vals_dict):
...     #creating element constraints
...     constraint_elements = '\n'.join([var+' == '+str(element_vals_dict[var]) for var in element_vals_dict])
...     return constraint_elements.lstrip() + '\n'
... 
>>> def constraints_func1(element_low_lim, element_hi_lim):
...     var_num = ['x'+str(i) for i in range(260)]
...     #creating element bounds constraints
...     constraint_bound = ''
...     for var in var_num:
...         if var not in element_vals_dict:
...             constraint_bound += var + f' >= {element_low_lim}' + '\n' + var + f' <= {element_hi_lim}' + '\n'
...     return constraint_bound.lstrip()
... 
>>> def constraints_func2(total_matrix_min_sum, total_matrix_max_sum):
...     var_num = ['x'+str(i) for i in range(260)]
...     #creating sum of all the elements constraint
...     constraint_matrix_sum = ' + '.join(var_num) + f' <= {total_matrix_max_sum}' + '\n' + ' + '.join(var_num) + f' >= {total_matrix_min_sum}'
...     return constraint_matrix_sum.lstrip() + '\n'
... 
>>> def constraints_func3(column_sum_min_lst, column_sum_max_lst):
...     var_num = ['x'+str(i) for i in range(260)]
...     #creating column sum constraints
...     constraint_column_sum = ''
...     for i in range(5):
...         columns_var = var_num[i::5]
...         column_max_sum = ' + '.join(columns_var) + f' <= {column_sum_max_lst[i]}'
...         column_min_sum = ' + '.join(columns_var) + f' >= {column_sum_min_lst[i]}'
...         constraint_column_sum += '\n' + column_max_sum + '\n' + column_min_sum
...     constraint_column_sum += '\n'
...     return constraint_column_sum.lstrip()
... 
>>>
```

I'll build the constraints now, but as there are some unnecessary constraints in `eqn3`, I'm going to get rid of them. Essentially, `merge` identifies that `CON <= 0` and `CON >= 0`, together, don't apply any constraint.

```
>>> # build the constraints
>>> eqn0 = constraints_func0(element_vals_dict)
>>> eqn1 = constraints_func1(element_low_lim, element_hi_lim)
>>> eqn2 = constraints_func2(total_matrix_min_sum, total_matrix_max_sum)
>>> eqn3 = constraints_func3(column_sum_min_lst, column_sum_max_lst)
>>> 
>>> # remove unnecessary constraints
>>> eqn3 = '\n'.join(ms.merge(*eqn3.strip().split('\n'))) + '\n'
>>>
```

Now, I need to isolate something other than `x0`, `x1`, or `x2`... so I could either go back and not include the above three variable in the relevant equations until after simplification, or I have to work a bit to isolate something else.  I'll sloppily do the isolation however I can with what I have.

```
>>> # isolate non-fixed single variables, where relevant
>>> eqn3c = sorted(eqn3.strip().split('\n'))
>>> eqn3a = ms.simplify('\n'.join(eqn3c[:2])+'\n', all=True, target='x5') + '\n' 
>>> eqn3b = ms.simplify('\n'.join(eqn3c[2:4])+'\n', all=True, target='x6') + '\n'
>>> eqn3c = ms.simplify('\n'.join(eqn3c[4:])+'\n', all=True, target='x7') + '\n' 
>>> eqn2 = ms.simplify(eqn2, all=True, target='x3') + '\n'
```

We then combine, and generate the constraints.

```
# combine simplified equations and generate constraints
equations = eqn0 + eqn1 + eqn2 + eqn3a + eqn3b + eqn3c
constrain = ms.generate_constraint(ms.generate_solvers(equations), join=my.constraints.and_)
```

Set up the solver...

```
>>> def obj_func(x):
...     kx = constrain(x)
...     y =  sum(kx)
...     return y
... 
>>> mon = my.monitors.VerboseMonitor(1)
>>> obj_vals = []
>>> def callback(x):
...     kx = constrain(x)
...     y =  sum(kx)
...     mon(kx, y)
...     obj_vals.append(y)
... 
>>> # create a starting matrix
>>> start_matrix = [random.randint(0,3) for i in range(260)]
```

then solve...

```
>>> # run optimizer
>>> solution = so.minimize(obj_func, start_matrix, method='SLSQP', tol=0.01, options={'disp': True, 'maxiter':100}, callback=callback)
Generation 0 has ChiSquare: 783.0
Generation 1 has ChiSquare: 2073.8870967741877
Generation 2 has ChiSquare: 668.5887699219646
Generation 3 has ChiSquare: 856.5643183986956
Generation 4 has ChiSquare: 620.5068341441591
Generation 5 has ChiSquare: 785.2132279949118
Generation 6 has ChiSquare: 730.8870714406557
Generation 7 has ChiSquare: 655.2910093597624
Generation 8 has ChiSquare: 628.109917778625
Generation 9 has ChiSquare: 630.5176087171566
Generation 10 has ChiSquare: 605.725338759661
Generation 11 has ChiSquare: 610.5089572225905
Generation 12 has ChiSquare: 606.1689809653246
Generation 13 has ChiSquare: 600.0869446386264
Generation 14 has ChiSquare: 600.0
Optimization terminated successfully    (Exit mode 0)
            Current function value: 600.0
            Iterations: 15
            Function evaluations: 3933
            Gradient evaluations: 15
```

Then print the solution:

```
>>> df_solution = pd.DataFrame(np.array(mon.x[-1]).reshape(-1,5), columns=['Col1','Col2','Col3','Col4','Col5'])
>>> print(df_solution)
     Col1   Col2   Col3  Col4  Col5
0   100.0  200.0  300.0   0.0   0.0
1     0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
2     0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
3     0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
4     0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
5     0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
6     0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
7     0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
8     0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
9     0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
10    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
11    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
12    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
13    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
14    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
15    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
16    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
17    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
18    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
19    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
20    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
21    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
22    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
23    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
24    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
25    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
26    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
27    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
28    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
29    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
30    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
31    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
32    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
33    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
34    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
35    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
36    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
37    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
38    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
39    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
40    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
41    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
42    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
43    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
44    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
45    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
46    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
47    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
48    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
49    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
50    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
51    0.0    0.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
```

Hopefully, that looks right.

Comment: Hi @Mike, many thanks. I've updated my constraint values to the actual values I need. However, the code seems to get stuck at ```eqn3c = ms.simplify('\n'.join(eqn3c[4:])+'\n', all=True, target='x7') + '\n'``` ?

Comment: That seems odd... in either case, it's essentially just selecting the one `x7` instance, and subtracting all the other variables from both sides.  Your constraints equations are simple enough that you could construct them so they are already simplified (i.e. there's no nonlinear interdependency of variables).  Although, it could be memory issues... in that case, you can simplify one equation at at time instead of multiple.

Comment: All equations (```eqn3a```, ```eqn3b```, ```eqn3c```, ```eqn2```) are being simplified separately already right?  I tried running each simplify equation separately, still getting the issue with ```eqn3c```. Not sure why this is happening?

Comment: Yes. Not sure why you are experiencing a hang. It can also happen if there's an error.  You can try some of the different options, especially `verbose=True`.  I generally use that to help me get an idea where it is having an issue. If you are still experiencing it getting stuck there... it might be a better suited as a mystic GitHub issue (as opposed to in the comments on SO).

Comment: Hi Mike,  have just included the actual ```obj_func```.  Just wondering if it's the ```obj_func``` that's causing the issue? Will post on mystic GitHub if issue persists :)